# how to throw an exception when using terms look up

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I used terms lookup to fast terms search with elasticsearch, but I have a need that if the index which I fetch term data from doesn't have such an id that I post, I want to get an exception from elasticsearch, is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var settings = new ConnectionConfiguration(new Uri("http://example.com:9200"))
    .OnRequestCompleted(apiCallDetails =>
    {
        if (apiCallDetails.HttpStatusCode == 418)
        {
            throw new TimeForACoffeeException();
        }
    });

var lowlevelClient = new ElasticLowLevelClient(settings);
```

from [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/elasticsearch-net-getting-started.html).

Comment: Sorry, I mean if elasticsearch can throw an exception.

Comment: take a look here. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/elasticsearch-net-getting-started.html

Comment: you have to go thru apiCallDetails and find if there is any result. if not, throw custom error